# Color the TabPanel in TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, componentone

I am using **Component One control for WPF screen design**. I want to apply the background color in c1Tabcontrol header panel.

[image]

Comment: Use snoop to find out the panel name, and see if it has any additional properties. It's also useful to know if the background is binded against something.

Comment: Or try to use Blend and edit template for C1TabControl. Look for TabPanel. C1TabControl has no dependency property that will allow you to set Background color for TabPanel.

Answer (score 0):

You are suggested to set the Background of the container control in which you have added your C1TabControl.

Thanks,
Prashant